# simple function $f(x)$ for which $x^{1/x} -1 \sim f(x)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math

$f(x) \sim g(x)$ iff $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$. Find a simple function $f(x)$ for which $x^{1/x} -1 \sim f(x)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

I know that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x^{1/x} = 1$ so I was thinking of using a function that tends towards $0$. However, I didn't really get very far past that.

Comment: You don't know a function similar to $0$ at infinity?

Comment: For starters, you need to define precisely what you mean by $\sim$.

Comment: What do you want to count as "simple"?  As functions go, $f(x) = x^{1/x}-1$ isn't so terrible.

Comment: Do you know what is a simple function for which $e^x-1\sim f(x)$ as $x\to0$? Hint: these questions are kinda related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^{\frac{1}{x}}-1=e^{\frac{\log x}{x}}-1\underset{x\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\frac{\log x}{x}$$
because $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\log x}{x}=0$ and $e^t-1\underset{t\rightarrow 0}{\sim}t$.